# Set BufDelete autocmd for particular filetype

Tags: vim

I'm writing a small snippet for `quickfix` buffers. I need to add an `autocmd` for `quickfix` buffers for `BufDelete` event.

I have following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim`

```
augroup quickr_preview
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufDelete <buffer> echom "Hey"
augroup END
```

The `autocmd` is getting executed before the `quickfix` buffer is loaded. So the `BufDelete` `autocmd` gets set for the calling buffer and not the `quickfix` buffer.

I've also tried putting `autocmd FileType qf autocmd BufDelete <buffer> echom "Hey"` directly in my `~/.vimrc`, but that has same effect.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I'm going with following.

```
function! QuickFixBufDelete()
    if &buftype == 'quickfix'
        autocmd BufDelete <buffer> echom "Hey"
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufCreate * call QuickFixBufDelete()
```

This is not good as the `autocmd` gets invoked for all filetypes and then I check for the filetype in my function.

Comment: Note that, at least in NeoVim today, the help for `BufCreate` just says to use `BufAdd` instead. So maybe it was deprecated due to a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is no longer working for me. I am now trying the `BufReadPost` auto command, and it seems to be playing nicely ...

```
augroup quickr_preview_auto_cmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufReadPost quickfix
     \   if !exists('b:quickr_preview_auto_cmds')
     \ |     exe 'autocmd BufDelete <buffer> pclose! | sign unplace 26'
     \ |     let b:quickr_preview_auto_cmds = 1
     \ | endif
augroup END
```

This matches what is described in the vim help for qiuckfix-window ...

```
When the quickfix window has been filled, two autocommand events are
triggered.  First the 'filetype' option is set to "qf", which triggers the
FileType event.  Then the BufReadPost event is triggered, using "quickfix" for
the buffer name.  This can be used to perform some action on the listed
errors.
```

Comment: I am now using `autocmd FileType qf`, at it seems to be working fine. I have tested with vim/gvim 8.0 (patches 1-1839) and nvim (v0.2.2), using both quickfix and location lists.